# How to get token of parent entity in paragraph?

Tags: 8, tokens, paragraphs

I have a paragraph, which is referenced by a node. Now I am trying to pass field values of node to the paragraph using tokens. I'm only aware of `[paragraph:parent_id]` and `[paragraph:parent_type]` but don't know how to get specific field values.

What I've tried so far without success:
`[node:field_foo:value]`
`[paragraph:field_foo:value]`
`[paragraph:node:field_foo:value]`
`[paragraph:parent:field_foo:value]`
`[paragraph:parent:entity:field_foo:value]`

The list of available tokens does not contain parent tokens. Is it even possible to get token of the parent entity? And if so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing out of the box (see [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2444671) for the details). Implementing your own token isn't too tricky.

I haven't had a chance to test this but I'm pretty sure it'll work:

```
function MODULE_token_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['tokens']['paragraph']['parent_entity'] = [
    'name' => 'Parent entity',
    'description' => 'Parent entity of the paragraph',
  ];
}

function MODULE_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];

  if ($type == 'paragraph' && $paragraph = $data['paragraph']) {
    $parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();
    $bubbleable_metadata->addCacheableDependency($parent);

    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      if ($name == 'parent_entity') {
        $replacements[$original] = $parent->label();
      }
    }

    $token_service = \Drupal::token();
    if ($parent_entity_tokens = $token_service->findWithPrefix($tokens, 'parent_entity')) {
      $replacements += $token_service->generate($parent->getEntityTypeId(), $parent_entity_tokens, [$parent->getEntityTypeId() => $parent], $options, $bubbleable_metadata);
    }
  }

  return $replacements;
}
```

Comment: I did not found an issue regarding version 8.x, so I was hoping that parent tokens might be available out of the box. But your code does work. Thanks for introducing me in custom tokens.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail about the what the token_service section does? I assume it is trying to get sub-tokens for the parent entity EG. [paragraph:parent_entity:field_body]? If so though it is not working for me.
$parent_entity_tokens is an empty array.

Comment: The above code does work great to provide all the entity sub tokens but unfortunately it only shows the new parent token in the token browser.

Comment: Kudos for @Clive, I've added this as MR on this issue https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3067265

Answer (score 4):

So with the newest version of Drupal 8 and Paragraphs, this is possible.

Looking at the tokens on `/admin/help/token`, there is a `[paragraph:parent_entity]` under the paragraphs section which is exactly what you need.

Example use case: to get the title of the parent node, I used `[paragraph:parent_entity:title]`.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the corresponding Drupal issue?

Comment: @PhilippMichael I'm not sure what you mean. There was no drupal issue that I know about; I just went to `/admin/help/token/` and the token was listed. Do you mean the issue mentioned in Clive's answer? That was actually a Drupal 7 issue (I couldn't find any issues about this for Drupal 8)

Comment: No bugfix or feature without a Drupal issue. Just wanted to know if it was already available when I asked this question or solved in the meantime. Nevermind.

Comment: Can't find `[paragraph:parent_entity:title]` but `[paragraph:parent_field_name:value]` using Paragraphs 8.x-1.8 and Token 8.x-1.1

Comment: none of the paragraph:parent entities work in Drupal 8.6.10

Comment: On 9.2.11 I don't see a parent_entity token.